# Discord.NET exception in getting text channel

Tags: c#, exception, discord, discord.net

The code  is my attempt at posting a message to a specific channel in a server.

The exception below appears on the line beginning "var channel..."
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

`<guild>5__2 was null.`

Console.writeline(guild) gives the guild name.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static async void AutoCat()
          {

                CATS();
                var eb = new EmbedBuilder();
                eb.WithTitle("CAT!");
                eb.WithImageUrl(catURL);
                var guild = _client.GetGuild("IdHere");
                Console.WriteLine(guild);
                var channel = guild.GetTextChannel("IdHere");

                channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, eb.Build());
            
            

          }
```

Comment: Make sure you're calling AutoCat after _client.Ready has fired. If guild isn't null (because Console.WriteLine worked), how are you getting a NRE? Could it be your channel id parameter that is null?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on `var channel = guild.GetTextChannel("IdHere");` and verify that guild is not null